# export and import data from mongodb using node.js express

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I want to export all data from my server to my local(also i don't have a backup so this will serve as a backup. So I used the below code to get the collection in a json format and save to the local.

I am using mongodb and node express.

```
dbName.find().exec(function(err, output){

var jsonOutput=JSON.stringify(output)

fs.writeFile('downloads/output.json', output, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send('error')
        }
        else{
            var filename = 'res.json'
            var mimetype = 'application/json'

            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename)
            res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype)
            res.end(jsonOutput)
        }
    })
})
```

This gives me what I want. Now I want to process the json in my local machine so that my local data is in sync with the server.

1. How to store all the data in bulk to the backend?
2. I have few references between the schema, so will new '_id' be created
   hence affecting my references
3. If you think this is not the right way to export the data, how can
       it be done using node express?

Answer (score 2):

try to use `mongodump` or `mongoexport`. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/

mongoexport provide efficent way to export data from collection (by query if you want)

mongodump makes a full database dump (backup) so you can easily restore it anywhere, with the same ids, references, indexes. All your stuff

You can use node.js `child_process.exec` for running mongodump/mongoexport. You can use linux `crontab` for scheduling backups. So many ways to organize this with right tools

Comment: I just tried to list all the collection names for testing using child_process exec. But I keep on getting stderr: getCollectionsNames is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: you can run mongodb commands via mongodb-driver https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native